# aspnet_compiler verbosity and result

Tags: asp.net, precompile, aspnet-compiler

I'm using this command line to precompile **in place** a website (.net 2.0):

> aspnet_compiler -nologo -v MyApp

Everything run with several warnings (fair enough).

1. How can I understand if (warnings apart) the pre-compilation did its
   job?
2. can I write the results in an output files
3. can I tune the verbosity?

Thanks